# Is there debug.exe equivalent for linux?

Tags: windows, alternative

Is there a Windows `debug.exe` equivalent where I can write machine code and see what results they have after execution?

Comment: NASM? The Netwide Assembler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can emulate debug.exe from DOSBOX...

- make a dir in your computer and paste in it debug.exe
- open dosbox and mount your dir with: `mount x /home/[user]/[folderCreated]`
- change to x:
- run debug.exe

Comment: DOSBox comes with a built-in debugger, if you build it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)
Maybe it will help you.

You can 'set write on' after opening an executable with gdb.

Then you can use 'set *(unsigned char *)(hex_address) = machine_code_of_an_instruction'
to change the machine code at hex_address.

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you're looking for is [winegdb](http://linux.die.net/man/1/winedbg). Initially, it should allow you to debug Win32 applications in Linux.